# how to add scrollable tab bar with scrollable custom view controller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollbar, tabbar

I like to add scrollable tab bar with scrollable custom view controller in iOS like as google play store.[android play store screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQeto.jpg).

Thank you...

Comment: check this...https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tabview

Answer (score 1):

**ThirdParty**

if you like to move on ThirdParty use [MXSegmentedPager](https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager)

**Native**

else if you want to work around in Native , customize yourSelf

1. create the one common `UIScrollView`, like name `tblScroll`
2. Create the one common `UIView` like Name `viewSubBack`'

   on `UISCrollViewDelegate` method

   ```
   // this is the line for calculate the deviceWidth
   #define KAPPDeviceWidth [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width

   - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
   {

       if (self.tblScroll.contentOffset.x<KAPPDeviceWidth/2)
       {
           self.viewSubBack.frame=CGRectMake(self.tblScroll.contentOffset.x, 106, 160, 5); // the view changes related to your x - coordinates change
       }
       else
       {
           self.viewSubBack.frame=CGRectMake((KAPPDeviceWidth/2)+1, 106, 160, 5);
       }

   }
   ```

for Pods error

remove the workspace and run pod install again:

```
rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace
pod install
```

Comment: i received pod file error in using MXSegmentedPager.how to import pod file in to project.

Comment: can you show the error

Comment: diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: You should close Xcode, run pod install, then open it again. Xcode is sometimes not able to pick up changes on the filesystem while it is open.

Comment: @Barani --check the alternate answer

Comment: [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: chck once this link https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiNobedgs7IAhVNHo4KHbYQDlM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.raywenderlich.com%2F64546%2Fintroduction-to-cocoapods-2&usg=AFQjCNEiXVufJUoU8zVQ7ZaiRmipQy-Svg&bvm=bv.105454873,d.c2E&cad=rja

Comment: @Barani -- in my answer is working or not

Comment: @karthik - how to take file path

Comment: @Barani -- it is not related to your question , if you need much more create the another question and ask, the above answer is working or not

Comment: @karthick - its working fine..

Comment: @Barani -- then give the upvote , stackoverflow does not agree the multiple question in the single question , so ask in another question ,

Comment: @karthik - i dont have a 15 reputation.